# How to Start Gimp .png with Brightness/Contrast controllers?

Tags: 16.04, brightness, gimp, image-processing, contrast

Situation: start Gimp .png with brightness/contrast options as one-liner in terminal
Motivation: have a plane of brightness-contrast where you can control them on x-axis and y-axis; synonym *non-linear plane of brightness-contrast*, ... (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299246/16920) for its expected output at the end of the question body)

Pseudocode to get the mode *Colours > Curves*

```
gimp --contrast --brightness file.png
```

### Related issue simply starting Gimp in Ubuntu 16.04

Related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1576977. 
I do

```
gimp file.png
```

Output in Terminal

```
(gimp:4270): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'

(gimp:4270): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1A523C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"

(gimp:4270): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1A52890 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"

...

(gimp:4270): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1A58390 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"

(gimp:4270): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1A58730 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"

(gimp:4270): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1A58B90 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"
```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Gimp: 2.8.16
Related: [To Adjust Brightness-Contrast in Plane with Gimp/ImageMagick/…?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299246/16920) for Debian and Ubuntu